# Google sheet borders based on backgroundcolor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Since conditional format does not allow setting borders, is it possible to create a script and border a row based on the color of a cell / row?

If so how?

I found similar scripts, but no scripts based on background color.
I need something to get started / push in the right direction....

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer explaining what methods to use to get the background colors and to set the borders. I didn't provide any script, since you didn't provide details about your request. I hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Range.getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) to get the background color from one cell, or [Range.getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) to get the background colors from multiple cells.

You can then use that information to set your desired borders, using [Range.setBorder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal).